# How can i create dynamic button click event on dynamic button - VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling, dynamic-controls

I am creating a button on page dynamically. now i want to use button click event on that button. How can i do this in VB.net & asp.net?

**My code:**

**Page Load:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Try
               LoadControls()
             Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub
```

**Load Controls**

```
   Private Sub LoadControls()
    Try
       Dim ButtonTable As New HtmlTable
       Dim ButtonTableRow As New HtmlTableRow
       Dim ButtonTableCell As New HtmlTableCell
       Dim btnCode As New Button
           btnCode.ID = "btnCode"
           btnCode.Text = "btnCode"
           AddHandler btnCode.Click, AddressOf btnCode_Click
       ButtonTableCell.Controls.Add(btnCode)

       ButtonTableRow.Cells.Add(ButtonTableCell)
       ButtonTable.Rows.Add(ButtonTableRow)

       ControlsPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(ButtonTable)
 Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

**Event Handler**

```
Private Sub btnCode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

            Dim buttonId As New Button
            Try
                buttonId = DirectCast(sender, Button)

                // My execution
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub
```

**Problem:**

event handler doesn't arises..!!  it throws an error

`Multiple controls with the same ID were found`

What is wrong with this code..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating a dynamic button "subscribe" your eventhandler `btnCode_Click` to event of the button:

```
AddHandler btnCode.Click, AddressOf btnCode_Click
```

Then `EventHandler` must be at least `Protected`, but your is `Private` - it cannot be accessed then

Comment: have you seen my code?? i have this part of line in the code, but it doesn't works

Comment: You have a typo in the line with `AddHandler...` check eventhandler's name

Comment: no that is not the issue here, that typo occured while posting it here..!!

Comment: still the problem exists..!! i have changed it to protected..!!

Comment: What is `btnSummary` is in your code? And I think using `try..catch` without handling `exception` will just hide a errors - difficult to debug...

Comment: button is not firing at all in my case..!! it throws an error **Multiple controls with the same ID were found**