# How would I handle a click event for a Programmatically created for a button?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I would like to click a button I have created programmatically, and for it to generate a message box (Visual Basic)
This is the code that generates the button:

```
Dim NodeButton As New Control
NodeButton.Name = "Button" & NodeID
NodeButton.BackColor = Color.Red
NodeButton.Text = NodeID
NodeButton.Size = New Point(ButtonSize, ButtonSize)
NodeButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Xcoordinate, YCoordinate)
frmMain.Controls.Add(NodeButton)
NodeButton.BringToFront()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic button click event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375061/dynamic-button-click-event-handler)

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291461/how-do-i-create-an-event-handler-for-a-programmatically-created-object-in-vb-net) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642678/how-can-i-create-dynamic-button-click-event-on-dynamic-button-vb-net) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948332/how-to-make-a-click-event-for-runtime-created-controls-in-visual-basic-2010)

Comment: Google your title and the answer will probably be there for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an `EventHandler`

```
AddHandler theButton.Click, AddressOf Me.theButton_Click
```

Then in your handling method you need to compare the `sender` with your button object. If they match, you can work with this button.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents NodeButton As Button

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Me.NodeButton = New Button()
        ' Add it to UI
        AddHandler Me.NodeButton.Click, AddressOf Me.nodeButton_Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub nodeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If (sender Is Me.NodeButton) Then
            'Do what you want
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```